# downloaded laravel project and can't login Can you help me?

Tags: laravel, laragon

downloaded laravel project from my server open it with laragon but i can't login. Can you help me?

i presume that i'm missing the database but i don't know how to migrate it and not sure if i have the correct password. i inherited the app so i don't have to much info. any help is much apreciated

Comment: Read the docs...

Comment: you need to create the database, put the valid credentials for it into the .env and run php artisan migrate. That will create the table structures for you. If you do php artisan db:seed, it should seed the tables. and looking through your seeders you probably can find the default password. (usually something like secret)

Comment: there are two databases in the .env file I've created both of them there is a password and a user name. when i do php artisan db:seed i have an error  Application In Production!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi guys i managed to fix it by exporting the databases from Cpanel phpmyadmin and importing in them in the laragon phpmyadmin
thank you